# Cron not working with post method in Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I am working on Rest api using codeigniter,I created a function and i want that function should be call 
in a day (within 24 hours) so in cron job section of cpanel i put following command

```
wget -O - -q http://mydomain/api/Users/crontest_post
```

but its not working,If i replace post with get method then working fine,But i want to execute with post method
How can i do this ?

Comment: You do not have terminal when run in `cron`. So where write `-O - `?